# How do I create time to be store as mysql TIMESTAMP type, in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I create time to be store as mysql TIMESTAMP type, in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the PHP side, you can use the [date](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

`$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 3):

use now() in select query.

like this,

```
   dattime = now();
```